# How to set up Apple car play in Toyota Auris 2018

Tags: toyota, infotainment

I am trying to connect apple car play with my 2018 Toyota Auris. Does anyone know if Toyota Auris 2018 supports apple car play or how to set it up?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!